# How can I import data from an xml file and parse them in a NSCombobox using cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Hi I want to parse data from an xml file into a combobox using cocoa. I didn't find how to import data from my xml file.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

To import data into NSDate object you can use something like this:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"xmlfile" ofType: @"xml"];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: path];
```

For parsing xml you can use NSXMLParser or some 3rdparty code like, for example: TBXML.
With TBXML you can load xml like this:

```
TBXML * tbxml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithXMLFile:@"books.xml"];
```

Comment: Thanks :) Can you send me a tutorial that shows that ? and what about the nscombobox ? do I need to use datasource ?

Comment: @user1503496 For parsing XML you can use this TBXML guid [link](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/Guides.html), as for nscombobox, i think using datasource is more convenient but if wont change it a lot in run time you can use internal list, just put object into array from xml and use methods from documentation fro nscombobox [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ComboBox/Tasks/ProvidingComboBoxData.html) in the bottom of this page